# Can't use variable inside of an IBAction outside of it

Tags: ios, xcode

Can't use variable inside of an IBAction outside of it

Code:

```
if timerRunning==true && timerCount==actualWorkoutLength {
    timer.invalidate()
    timerRunning = false
    timerCount=0
    timerLabel.text="0 secs"
    intervalAlert()
}
```

Screenshot: [image: http://i.gyazo.com/86e0143893413c2dd50d59ecba7cf460.png]

Comment: did you set up an @IBoutlet for actualWorkoutLength from your interface to your code?

Comment: There isn't a label for the actualWorkoutLength, it's just a variable that holds a value that is calculated  `var actualWorkoutLength=sliderValue/2`

Comment: @donnywals It may also be useful to note that this variable is not inside the startButton IBAction but inside of another IBAction called sliderChanged.

Comment: @donnywals Here's a screenshot of all the code for the timer functionality http://i.gyazo.com/9da9f96c6c946472e68ddd7a640b87d9.png

Answer (score 0):

I look your screenshot and `actualWorkoutLength` is a local variable of another method.

BTW: In `startButton(sender: UIButton)` you will never see it.

If you want to see it. Declare `actualWorkoutLength` as `global variable`

Comment: I declared timerMaximum as a global variable which holds the value of actualWorkoutLength. Although the if statement returns no errors, it doesn't work... http://i.gyazo.com/e15889a40f626e3cffe48a032f828325.png Can you help me please? :-)

Comment: The timer just continues past the actualWorkoutLength which is calculated when the user uses the slider. I used it and changed the value to 6 seconds but the timer continued to count after 6 seconds... :(

Comment: I made another question, have a look in case it helps to understand the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721379/how-to-set-nstimer-limit-for-counting