# How to set NSTimer limit for counting?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I set a NSTimer limit for counting?

Firstly, to get a feel of my problem, here's a screenshot of my Xcode project - http://i.gyazo.com/178450cfdbf45a2508856cc79fd215ec.png

Secondly, here's the code to understand what's going wrong -

```
    else if timerRunning==true && timerCount==timerMaximum {
        timer.invalidate()
        timerRunning = false
        timerCount=0
        timerLabel.text="0 secs"
        intervalAlert()
    }
```

I tried to do this and the code takes no effect on the execution of the program. The timer continues to count after the timerMaximum variable (which I made sure is global).

I figured that this has something to do with...

```
if timerRunning==false{
        timer=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timerRunning=true
    }
```

Although, I'm not too sure.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks so much!

Jamie

Comment: You will have an issue if `timerMaximum` is 0 because you are using `==`.  I would suggest you try `else if timerRunning==true && timerCount >= timerMaximum`  Also, it is better to include the relevant code in your question rather than using a screen shot.  Also I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve by having this test in the `start` method - surely you would want to stop the timer once the maximum was reached in the `Counting` function (which, by convention should be `counting` with a small c).

Comment: I tried `else if timerRunning==true && timerCount >= timerMaximum` and it didn't work. How do I stop it in the `Counting` function?

Comment: I put the if statement into the `Counting` function and it worked!!!

Comment: The code you have that calls `timer.invalidate()` should stop the timer.  Really, `timer` should be declared as `timer?` and then you can set it to nil after you invalidate it. You can then replace your `timerRunning` boolean with a test for `timer` being non-nil

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense.  Where you had the code before the timer would only stop if you pressed the "start" button again

Answer (score 0):

Check and restrict timerCount in `counting` method. Like :

```
func Counting() {

    timerCount+=1

    if timerCount == timeraximum {

        self.stop()
    }
    else {

        timerLabel.text =“\(timerCount) seconds”
    }
```

Comment: Although it may seem to be helpful, to kindly ask anymore people from trying to answer my question, this is how I got around the problem http://i.gyazo.com/cf2434d042ae11f204a763b2b612c6cd.png Thanks for the help! :-)